# lastIndexOf using regex in elisp

Tags: elisp, emacs24

```
(last-index-of needle str &opt case-sens)
```

for ex,

```
(last-index-of "car" "carbikecar'")
```

must return

```
7
```

how can one do this in elisp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish this you can use [`string-match`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Search.html) in a loop to search repeatedly through the input string, returning the index of any last match found:

```
(defun last-index-of (regex str &optional ignore-case)
  (let ((start 0)
        (case-fold-search ignore-case)
        idx)
    (while (string-match regex str start)
      (setq idx (match-beginning 0))
      (setq start (match-end 0)))
    idx))
```

Trying your example:

```
(last-index-of "car" "carbikecar'")
7
```

This search ignores case:

```
(last-index-of "ar" "carbikecaR" t)
8
```

Two regular expression searches, the first ignoring case:

```
(last-index-of "arb?" "carbikecaR" t)
8
(last-index-of "arb?" "carbikecaR")
1
```